# Decorators in python: Difference in the args interpretation in class and function based decorators

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am trying to create a generic function lifecycle handler in python.
Working in brief:

- Logs the signature and return values.
- Handles the exception with or without retry.
- Provide cleanup in case of exception.

The issue which I encountered while doing the cleanup is as follows:
Function-based decorator:

```
def handler(exception=Exception,cleanup=None):
def func_wrapper(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        response=None
        try:
            print(args)
            response=func(*args,**kwargs)
        except exception as ex:
            print(f'Exception occurred:{str(ex)}\nCleaning up resources')
            #Passing the object for cleanup, it fails for class based decorators as it does not passes self as argument
            cleanup(args[0])
        return response
    return wrapper
return func_wrapper
```

The data which is supposed to be cleaned up is stored in the class instance and is cleaned based on the method provided.
For example:

- Store some information using third party API.
- In case of exception, the cleanup operation passed would invoke a
  delete API.

  ```
    class Test:
       def __init__(self,data):
           self.main_data=data


       @handler(exception=Exception,cleanup=lambda x:print(f"Cleaning data:{x.main_data}"))
       def test_data(self):
           print(f'Data is :{self.main_data}')
           i=1/0
  ```

Output:

```
Exception occurred:division by zero
Cleaning up resources
Cleaning:John Doe
```

I was more inclinded towards Class based decorator.

```
class LifeCycleHandler:
    def __init__(self,*,func=None,exception=Exception,cleanup=None):
        self.__exception=exception
        self.__cleanup=cleanup
        self.__func=func

    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        response=None
        try:
            print(args)
            response=self.__func(*args,**kwargs)
        except self.__exception as ex:
            print(f'Exception occurred:{str(ex)}\n cleaning up resources')
            #Passing the object for cleanup
            self.__cleanup(args[0])
        return response
```

```
def lifecycle_handler(exception=Exception,cleanup=None):
    def wrapper(func): 
        response=LifeCycleHandler(func=func,exception=exception,cleanup=cleanup)
        return response
    return wrapper
```

With class based decorator with similar functionality i faced the following error:

```
()
Exception occurred:test_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
 cleaning up resources
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in __call__
    response=self.__func(*args,**kwargs)
TypeError: test_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 54, in <module>
    test.test_data()
  File "test.py", line 31, in __call__
    self.__cleanup(args[0])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Can someone guide me regarding the the argument interpretation for callable classes?

Comment: I assume your ``lifecycle_handler`` is not a method of ``LifeCycleHandler``, right? Is it a typo?

Comment: @Ke Zhang : Thank you for the reply, yes it is a typo. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my comment correct, you could add `__get__` to `LifeCycleHandler`.

```
def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
    return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
```

This will make `test_data` become a non-data descriptor. I assume you already know [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). If not, it's definitely worth to check it.

Back to your question, from trace back, your assumed that python will help you pass the caller instance which is instance of `Test` as second argument to `__call__`. That's not true. However, that's true in `__get__`.

Your core logic (try/except block) needs are:

- instance of `Test`, because you need access to `main_data`.
- instance of `LifeCycleHandler` in, because you need access to your `self.__func`.
- args in which isn't acceptable in `__get__`, but you could have them in `__call__`.

For example, you have test code below:

```
t = Test(123)
t.test_data()
```

`t.test_data` will invoke `__get__`. In its arguments, `self` is an instance of `LifeCycleHandler` and `obj` is `t` (instance of `Test`). `__get__` returned a callable function(`__call__`) in which its first argument is partially feed by `obj`.